# Access ajax data, that I store into a PHP function?

Tags: php, ajax, function

Maybe I need to go about it another way, but here is what I am trying to do (it's simple) I send data to a PHP function using ajax. Here is an example.

```
function myAjax(){

      //The data here comes from an ajax call
      $_POST['id']; 
      $_POST['x'];
      $_POST['y']; 

}
```

The ajax looks like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: window.ajaxurl,
            data: { "action": "myAjax", id: divid, x: pos_x, y: pos_y }})   
}
```

This is not the complete ajax code, this is inside a jQuery UI event but it's irrelevant, the important part is the `data:{}`

The data from the PHP code is stored into a database, I run code inside the function to interact and add the variables, but again that is irrelevant... how can I access these variables outside of this function?

Lets say I am echoing a div and I want to use $_POST['id'] as an ID for that div. example

```
echo '<div id="'.$_POST['id'].'"></div>';
```

This code is obviously outside the function... so I am still a newbie and would be grateful if someone can point this out to me :)

Comment: Will the code that is output by your `echo` be in the result of the function call or be some markup on the page that is doing the `jQuery.ajax` call?

Comment: It seems to be a good candidate for a `switch` on the action, in which every case could echo something different based on the data provided.

Comment: I was hoping I made that clear but thanks for asking.. it for markup outside of the function... It works inside the function of course..

Comment: Okay, actually maybe it would be better to wrap all the markup inside the function

Comment: I just realized the markup is inside another function... how would I take ajax data from one function and put it into another function.. is there a way to connect the two

Comment: Perhapes I don't understand it right, but: `$_POST` is one of PHPs superglobals, which are available everywhere in every function and every scope. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to understand what data you are getting, you should do a `var_dump` in PHP:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

This will show a list of key/value pairs, based on that you can then output the information as needed.

Note that jQuery might do some automatic conversion on the data, for example it might convert your object to JSON. In this case, decode the data server-side using `json_decode`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to store request params somewhere and then pass them anywhere you need. For instance,

```
// well, this is quite straightforward
$requestParams = $_POST;

// then pass params to your function
function myAjax(array $params) {
    // here you have local copy of your $_POST parameters

    // EDITED: you can store data in database and return the result, an ID of
    // the row for example

    // some insert SQL
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    return $id;
}

$newRecordId = myAjax($requestParams);

// here (outside function) you have a global $params variable which you can use
// to echo a div for example
```

Comment: Ok seems logical.. let me give it a shot..... why store $_POST in a variable... it isnt so straightforward to me lol...

Comment: If $_POST['id'] is stored inside the function, I need to call global $params; ? then put $_POST['id'] inside an ID for example?

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify it. Anyway using `global` is not a good practise.